# Does this R code look ok to expand out to other sites?

Tags: datetime, r, ftp

I'm after some constructive criticism on my code and maybe some ways to simplify before I expand it to include other sites. I am new to R and coding and have been working on this problem for weeks now.

I need to graph the last 10 days of data from 20 remote sites. There are 3 csv files from each site that I bring in via FTP. I will be running this every half hour as new data is written to the csv files.

My main problem has been the dynamic IP address/folder path which changes every month. So on the first day of the month, the csv files I download will be in a new folder.

My fix so far has been to download the last months data and this months new data, then combine these and filter for last 10 days only. I have a working solution but it's not very elegant and after the 10th day of each month it is downloading data which I don't even need or use.

What I would like is to only download the new data every half hour and append to the old data. Also accounting for any site outage which happens occasionally.

I realise my code is not reproducible, but it is working and I am mainly looking for red flags/tips to shorten or better ways of writing/other ideas to consider.

So here it is, I really appreciate the criticism, go hard, but be kind :)

```
#SiteA
SiteAip <- "10.10.10.10"
SiteA <- "usernamea"
PW <- "passwd"

#SiteB
SiteBip <- "20.20.20.20"
SiteB <- "usernameb"
PW <- "passwd"

library(tidyverse)
library(data.table) 
library(lubridate)

# This months date format to build folder path for current month download
Year <-format(Sys.Date(), format="%Y")
Month <- format(Sys.Date(), format="%B")
MM <- format(Sys.Date(), format="%m")

# Last months date format to build folder path for last month download
LM <- format(Sys.Date() %m+% months(-1), format="%B")
Lmon <- format(Sys.Date() %m+% months(-1), format="%m")
LY <- format(Sys.Date() %m+% months(-1), format="%Y")

# Download last month csv1 file
SiteAcsv1old <- glue::glue("ftp://{SiteA}:{PW}@{SiteAip}/1data/SiteA/{LY}/{LM}/SiteA}{LY}-{Lmon} csv1.txt")
SiteAcsv1old <- fread(SiteAcsv1old, header = FALSE, select = c(1, 3, 4),
                    col.names = c("DateTime", "Latitude", "Longitude"), sep = " ")

# Download this month csv1 file
SiteAcsv1new <- glue::glue("ftp://{SiteA}:{PW}@{SiteAip}/1data/SiteA/{Year}/{Month}/SiteA}{Year}-{MM} csv1.txt")
SiteAcsv1new <- fread(SiteAcsv1new, header = FALSE, select = c(1, 3, 4),
                    col.names = c("DateTime", "Latitude", "Longitude"), sep = " ")

#append new to old csv1 data
SiteAcsv1app <- unique(rbindlist(list(SiteAcsv1old, SiteAcsv1new)))

# Last 10 days of csv1 data
SiteAcsv1ten <- SiteAcsv1app %>%
  filter(between(as_datetime(DateTime), Sys.Date() - 10, Sys.Date()))

#Last month csv2 file
SiteAcsv2old <- glue::glue("ftp://{SiteA}:{PW}@{SiteAip}/1data/SiteA/{LY}/{LM}/SiteA}{LY}-{Lmon}.csv2")
SiteAcsv2old <- fread(SiteAcsv2old, header = FALSE, select = c( 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 18), 
                 col.names = c("DateTime", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), sep = ",")

#This month csv2 file
SiteAcsv2new <- glue::glue("ftp://{SiteA}:{PW}@{SiteAip}/1data/SiteA/{Year}/{Month}/SiteA}{Year}-{MM}.csv2")
SiteAcsv2new <- fread(SiteAcsv2new, header = FALSE, select = c( 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 18), 
                 col.names = c("DateTime", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), sep = ",")

#append new to old csv2 data
SiteAcsv2app <- unique(rbindlist(list(SiteAcsv2old, SiteAcsv2new)))

# Last 10 days of csv2 data
SiteAcsv2ten <- SiteAcsv2app %>% 
  filter(between(as_datetime(DateTime), Sys.Date() - 10, Sys.Date()))

#Last month csv3 file
SiteAcsv3old <- glue::glue("ftp://{SiteA}:{PW}@{SiteAip}/1data/SiteA/{LY}/{LM}/SiteA}{LY}-{Lmon}.csv3")
SiteAcsv3old <- fread(SiteAcsv3old, header = FALSE, select = c( 1, 3), 
                  col.names = c("DateTime", "F"), sep = ",")

#This month csv3 file
SiteAcsv3new <- glue::glue("ftp://{SiteA}:{PW}@{SiteAip}/1data/SiteA/{Year}/{Month}/SiteA}{Year}-{MM}.csv3")
SiteAcsv3new <- fread(SiteAcsv3new, header = FALSE, select = c( 1, 3), 
                  col.names = c("DateTime", "F"), sep = ",")

#append new to old csv3 data
SiteAcsv3app <- unique(rbindlist(list(SiteAcsv3old, SiteAcsv3new)))

# Last 10 days of csv3 data
SiteAcsv3ten <- SiteAcsv3app %>% 
  filter(between(as_datetime(DateTime), Sys.Date() - 10, Sys.Date()))

# Timestamps for csv1/csv2/csv3 are different (out by a few minutes)
# I need to round each of these down to the nearest half hour and merge data tables on "DateTime" 

# Round "DateTime" to previous half hour - 
SiteAcsv1ten[, DateTime:=as_datetime(DateTime, tz = "Australia/Queensland")]
SiteAcsv1ten[, DateTime := floor_date(DateTime, "30 minutes")]

SiteAcsv2ten[, DateTime:=as_datetime(DateTime, tz = "Australia/Queensland")] 
SiteAcsv2ten[, DateTime := floor_date(DateTime, "30 minutes")]

SiteAcsv3ten[, DateTime:=as_datetime(DateTime, tz = "Australia/Queensland")] 
SiteAcsv3ten[, DateTime := floor_date(DateTime, "30 minutes")]

# merge csv2/csv3/csv1 by DateTime
SiteAall <- Reduce(merge, list(SiteAcsv2ten, SiteAcsv3ten, SiteAcsv1ten))

# Plot data - Just basic for the moment, I will add labels and pretty up later
SiteAplot1 <- ggplot(SiteAall) +
  geom_line(aes(DateTime, B), colour="green") + 
  geom_line(aes(DateTime, C), color="orange")
SiteAplot1 + labs(title = "SiteA1")

SiteAplot2 <- ggplot(SiteAall) +
  geom_line(aes(DateTime, D), colour="red") + 
  geom_line(aes(DateTime, F), color="blue")
SiteAplot2 + labs(title = "SiteA2")
## working up to here

############################################################################################################

#SiteB

# Same as SiteA but with necessary changes
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. Which version of FTP - *RFC 3659* including [MLST](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3659#section-7)?

Comment: Cheers for the welcome. No idea about any of that. But FTP is working fine for my purposes and seems pretty quick. File sizes are only about 30 - 300KB. Although I am not sure how it will go when I will be importing about 150 csv files by FTP every half hour.

Answer (score 1):

So, here is the criticism. :)

Generally, you can improve your code (and concurrently also solve most of your scaling up issues) by reorganizing your code into reusable functions and using descriptive variable names.

Please note that I did not check if the code below executes withouth an error!

## Library Imports at the Top Source Code

Generally, you put library imports at the top of the source code. Except you give some explanation of why you did not do it.

## Scaling to more Sites

### Site Credentials

Since you want to scale you code up to N sites, your code is clearly not sustainable. This starts here

```r
#SiteA
SiteAip <- "10.10.10.10"
SiteA <- "usernamea"
PW <- "passwd"

#SiteB
SiteBip <- "20.20.20.20"
SiteB <- "usernameb"
PW <- "passwd"
```

and this continous till the end of your code. Can you imagine touching all of your code if you want to add just one site? Ideally, this would all be done automatically. For now, I would propose the following.

```r
get.site.credentials <- function(path.to.site.credentials)
{
   return(read.csv(file = path.to.site.credentials, # YOUR SETTINGS GO HERE))
}
```

and then below your library imports you simply do

```r
df.site.credentials <- get.site.credentials(path = PATH)
```

and `PATH` should be the path to your csv file.

### Downloading CSV files

Downloading your csv files is also a repetitive task. So, we can wrap this into a function too.

```r
get.csv.file.via.ftp <- function(site.user.name, site.pw, site.ip,
                                 date.year, date.month, date.mm)
{
    # I'm not sure what you want to do here exactly, though .....
    ftp.url <- glue::glue("ftp://{site.user.name}:{site.pw}@{site.ip}/1data/SiteA/{date.year}/{date.month}/SiteA}{date.year}-{date.mm}.csv3")

    df <- fread(ftp.url,
                header = FALSE,
                select = c( 1, 3), 
                col.names = c("DateTime", "F"), sep = ",")

   return(df)
}
```

Please look carefully at variable `ftp.url`. This might not work for all of your code, e.g. when you have url's that are different. However, it is easy to fix this too. One way, for exampe, would be to introduce an `if` statement into the function that lets you choose your `url`.

## Month Format generation

Your code to get the date formats is unbelivabely similar. Hence, we can abstract here to.

```r
get.date.month <- function(integer)
{
    my.date <- c()

    my.date$year  <- format(Sys.Date() % m + % months(integer), format="%Y")
    my.date$month <- format(Sys.Date() % m + % months(integer), format="%B")
    my.date$mm    <- format(Sys.Date() % m + % months(integer), format="%m")

    return(my.date)
}

get.date.current.month <- function()
{
    return(get.date.month(0))
}

get.date.last.month <- function()
{
   return(get.date.month(-1))
}
```

By first abstracting the code into function `get.date.month` and then building two wrappers around it with `get.date.current.month` and `get.date.last.month` you seprate your code clearly and your intention becomes clear. Further, it avoids mistakes in the future because no one should touch the wrapper functions. Of course, you don't have to be that expressive. Also, I would try to find better function names.

## Final Comment

There are more things that can be improved in your code, mostly through abstracting most of your code into functions and using descriptive variables names - as stated at the beginning.

HTH!